# How to display iframe content without scrolling in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a website. I have a sidemenu bar and its menu list is from page and post of my wordpress blog. Now, everytime I select one of the menus, its content will display in one of my created templates and it will display in an Iframe.

The content of my created template have 'div' which has class of "collapse".
Everytime I trigger the collapse div, the content does not show completely unless I scroll it.

I want it to display without scrolling and increase the height of Iframe depending the size of my collapsible div.

[image: code]

Comment: your question have no code included. please look how you ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: im sorry sir,i just forgot to put my codes.
please see attached image.

Comment: Better replace the image with the actual code. Also: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="your URL" scrolling="no" width="100%" ></iframe>
<script>
var d = window.innerHeight;
window.document.getElementById('iframe').style.height = d+'px';
</script>
```

Comment: A little description explaining why/how this solves the question would be good, rather than just posting a bunch of code.

Comment: You can get the height of the browser and iframe height dynamically changed on different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir,
This actually works for me,but the problem is,whenever i try to make my screen smaller or try make it responsive,it doesnt work.

Comment: My code will work when you reload the page , responsive is the other thing related to css coding.

Comment: You need to reload the page when you change in screen size.